# Transparent UITableView on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, transparency

I've been trying to create a transparent table view recently but I'm not having much luck. The idea is to have a MapView (or anything for an example...) underneath the table view (grouped) where the table cells are solid but the rest of the table view is transparent, showing the map behind.

What I've done so far is create a UITableView and set the background colour to `clearColor`, however this isn't working too well! Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: UITableView itself does not draw anything except the background. So you should be able to display content in a background view once you set the table's backgroundColor to clear. So can you explain 'this isn't working too well?'

Comment: Well I have got that to work, however I can't get the table to show any of the cells. In another setup I have the table working as normal, but the background colour changing to clearColor doesn't work. I think this is because I'm not using a view controller when I get the bg to be transparent?

Comment: What about the backgroundView and text color of the UITableViewCell in  the first case, where the table is not showing any cells. In the other setup, you may need to redraw the tableView if you change the background color somewhere after the tableVIew is first displayed.

Comment: I've used the navigation based template, added a few items to the table and set the colour to clear. This works fine, however how do I add anything behind the table? If I try in the IB then it simply doesn't show :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put in multiple views in IB you need to make sure you are able to access them by making each one an IBOutlet and hooking them up to the File's Owner.
Then in the ViewDidLoad method for the corresponding view controller, set which views are in the back and which one is in the front by using`[self sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView]` and `[self bringSubviewToFront:foregroundView]`. You cannot set in what order the multiple views are displayed in the Interface Builder.